# Giving a number to matches in tournament bracket

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a system where I number each match in a tournament the following way:

```
Round 0   |   Round 1    |    Round 2
--------------------------------------

2 -----
       |-------- 1 ------
3 ------                |
                        |---- 0
5 -----                 |
       |-------- 4 ------
6 ------
```

What I'm trying to achieve is find the formulas where given a match number I can find the two previous match numbers and its next.
I had made a very similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117440/numbering-matches-in-tournament-bracket), the only difference is that I numbered the matches backwards, but I'm unable to find the solution for this case.

Note the number of rounds is variable so:

```
Round 0   |   Round 1    |    Round 2    |    Round 3
------------------------------------------------------

3 -----
       |-------- 2 ------
4 ------                |
                        |---- 1 ----------
6 -----                 |                 |
       |-------- 5 ------                 |
7 ------                                  |
                                          |------ 0
10 -----                                  |
       |-------- 9 ------                 |
11 -----                |                 |
                        |---- 8 ----------
13 -----                |
       |-------- 12 ----
14 -----
```

Comment: I don't see a nice formula.  The numbering is not regular enough to make an easy one.  Note that if you had three rounds, the predecessors of 0 would change to 1,8

Comment: I've seen that already, maybe my numbering is not the best one? Do you see a better approach that would allow me identify previous and next matches? I did it this way as I wanted to avoid the creation of a real tree structure with its `next` and `previous` members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment, if you number the last match $1$, the ones in the next to last round 2,3, the ones in the round before $4,5,6,7$ and so on, you can do it.  Match $n$ is followed by $\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$ and preceded by $2n, 2n+1$.  If you want to start with $0$, you can add $1$ to your match number, do this calculation, then subtract $1$;

Comment: I think that does not meet when rounds > 3. I've updated the question to reflect that I can have any number of rounds.

Comment: I believe it does.  The next round earlier is $8-15$ and in general the round $n$ before the final has numbers $2^n-(2^{n+1}-1)$  , so $12,13$ precede $6$ and are preceded by $24,25,26,27$

Comment: Oh so you're suggesting a different numbering than the one I'm doing, please check my updated question and confirm it to me please

Comment: Yes, I saw your comment asking if your number was the best one.  I believe it is not and proposed one that has more regularity to the numbers.  It permits some nice formulas.

Comment: Ok now I understand your approach. I see it is easier too to see the sibling numbers on a same round! Thank you very much!